# Algebraic Topology Hatcher Chapter 3.2 Problem 15

Tags: algebraic-topology

Problem Statement: For a fixed coefficient field $F$, define the Poincare series fo a space $X$ to be the formal power series $p(t) = \sum_i a_it^i$ where $a_i$ is the dimension of $H^i(X; F)$ as a vector space over $F$, assuming this dimension is finite for all $i$. Show that $p(X \times Y) = p(X)p(Y)$.

Notes: The way I approached this was to first multiply out the Poincare series for $X$ and $Y$
\begin{align}p(X)p(Y) &= \left(\sum_i dim(H^i(X; F))t^i\right)\left(\sum_i dim(H^i(Y; F))t^j\right)\\
&= \left(\sum_k\sum_{i+j = k} dim(H^i(X; F))dim(H^j(Y; F))t^k\right)
\end{align}
If I can show that
$$\sum_{i+j = k} dim(H^i(X; F))dim(H^j(Y; F)) = dim H^k(X \times Y; F)$$ then I am done. Theorem 3.16 tells us that $H^*(X; R) \otimes_R H^*(Y; r) \rightarrow H^*(X \times Y; R)$ is an isomorphism. Since the dimension across tensor products is multiplicative (I believe), therefore we have $dim (H^*(X; R)) dim (H^*(Y; r)) =dim(H^*(X \times Y; R))$. I am interested in $H^k$ as opposed to $H^*$ and this is where I get stuck

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also called the Kunneth formula.

https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Kunneth_formula_for_cohomology

Comment: Hatcher states it a little differently in this section that is why I was confused.